# Property of a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This question was asked in my assignment of operators and I am not able to prove this particular result.

**Question:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Show that if $\,T\in L(H)\,$ is a positive operator then for every $x\in H:\lVert Tx\rVert^2 \leqslant\lVert x\rVert\lVert T^2 x\rVert$.

Now, if $H$ is a Hilbert space, then $T$ is called a positive operator if $T$ is auto-adjoint and for every $x\in H : \langle Tx,x\rangle\geqslant0$ .

Then there are results that $\,T\!\cdot\!T\,$ is always auto-adjoint and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

But, I am not able to understand what result I should use to solve this question.

Do you mind helping me?

Comment: What may help is the fact that you do not need that $T$ is positive, the result in question holds for all $T$ self-adjoint (so $T=T^*$). Either way the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is a good place to start. Does this help already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we know that the positive operator $T$ is self-adjoint, then by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\|Tx\|^2 = |\langle Tx,Tx\rangle| = |\langle x,T^2x\rangle| \leq \|x\| \|T^2x\|.$$

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: I'm sorry, I mindlessly copied from the question. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5):

If $T$ is a positive operator, then $\langle Tx,y\rangle$ has all of the properties of an inner-product, except possibly strict positivity. So the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
     |\langle Tx,y\rangle|^2 \le \langle Tx,x \rangle \langle Ty,y\rangle.
$$
Now if you let $y=Tx$,
\begin{align}
           \|Tx\|^4 &\le \langle Tx,x\rangle \langle T^2x,Tx\rangle \\ &\le \|Tx\|\|x\|\|T^2x\|\|Tx\| \\
      \|Tx\|^2 &\le \|T^2x\|\|x\|.
\end{align}